# convert an array to a list of json

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I created an array object and i want to convert it like this on my sample output.

the output that i want:

```
[
    {
        "10:00": 2,
        "10:30": 2,
        "12:00": 2,
        "12:30": 2,
        "13:00": 1,
        "13:30": 1,
        "14:00": 1,
        "14:30": 1,    
        "15:00": 1,    
        "15:30": 1,
        "16:00": 1,
        "16:30": 1,
        "17:00": 1,
        "17:30": 1,
        "18:00": 1,
        "18:30": 1,
        "19:00": 1,
        "19:30": 1,
        "20:00": 1,
        "20:30": 1,
        "21:00": 1,
        "21:30": 1,
        "22:00": 1,
        "22:30": 1,
        "23:00": 1
    }    
]
```

but the here's what I got on my result

```
[
    {
        "10:00": 2
    },
    {
        "10:30": 2
    },
    {
        "12:00": 2
    },
    {
        "12:30": 2
    },
    {
        "13:00": 1
    },
    {
        "13:30": 1
    },
    {
        "14:00": 1
    },
    {
        "14:30": 1
    },
    {
        "15:00": 1
    },
    {
        "15:30": 1
    },
    {
        "16:00": 1
    },
    {
        "16:30": 1
    },
    {
        "17:00": 1
    },
    {
        "17:30": 1
    },
    {
        "18:00": 1
    },
    {
        "18:30": 1
    },
    {
        "19:00": 1
    },
    {
        "19:30": 1
    },
    {
        "20:00": 1
    },
    {
        "20:30": 1
    },
    {
        "21:00": 1
    },
    {
        "21:30": 1
    },
    {
        "22:00": 1
    },
    {
        "22:30": 1
    },
    {
        "23:00": 1
    }
]
```

I'm trying to convert my code into the output that i want using this code

```
$flat = array();

foreach($tempreserve->result as $v) {
    if (is_array($v)) {
        $flat = array_merge($flat, array_values_recursive($v));
    }
    else {
        $flat[] = $v;
    }
}
```

here is the array object:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [10:00] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [10:30] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [12:00] => 2
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [12:30] => 2
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [13:00] => 1
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [13:30] => 1
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [14:00] => 1
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [14:30] => 1
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [15:00] => 1
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [15:30] => 1
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [16:00] => 1
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [16:30] => 1
        )

    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [17:00] => 1
        )

    [13] => stdClass Object
        (
            [17:30] => 1
        )

    [14] => stdClass Object
        (
            [18:00] => 1
        )

    [15] => stdClass Object
        (
            [18:30] => 1
        )

    [16] => stdClass Object
        (
            [19:00] => 1
        )

    [17] => stdClass Object
        (
            [19:30] => 1
        )

    [18] => stdClass Object
        (
            [20:00] => 1
        )

    [19] => stdClass Object
        (
            [20:30] => 1
        )

    [20] => stdClass Object
        (
            [21:00] => 1
        )

    [21] => stdClass Object
        (
            [21:30] => 1
        )

    [22] => stdClass Object
        (
            [22:00] => 1
        )

    [23] => stdClass Object
        (
            [22:30] => 1
        )

    [24] => stdClass Object
        (
            [23:00] => 1
        )

)
```

Hope you guy's can help me on this problem
I want to use the time to get the number value

Comment: `array_merge()` returns an array. You're appending arrays to the `$flat` array.

Comment: done posting the array sir...

Comment: Why would you want to build an Object with Properties like that? `10:00` does not make a very sensible property name

Comment: Show us what `$tempreserve->result` actually contains.

Comment: the `$tempreseve->result` is `here is the array object:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$a=[];
$b=new stdClass();
$k1="12:00";
$k2="12:50";
$k3="13:10";
$b->$k1=1;
$b->$k2=2;
$b->$k3=3;
$a[]=$b;
echo json_encode($a);
```

result

```php
[{
    "12:00": 1,
    "12:50": 2,
    "13:10": 3
}]
```

Do you want results like this?

full version:

```php
$flat=new stdClass();
foreach($tempreserve as $obj) {
    $a=json_decode(json_encode($obj),true);
    $k=array_keys($a)[0];
    $v=$a[$k];
    $flat->$k=$v;
}
echo (json_encode($flat));
```

Comment: I doubt it, OP has an array and they want to convert it. This is all a bit manual :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` and `json_encode`, `$arr` is the array

```
$res = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
  foreach($value as $innerkey => $innerValue){
    $res[$innerkey] = $innerValue;
  }
}
echo json_encode($res);
```

[Live Demo](https://3v4l.org/GjcJF)